# how to get redirect_uri to fill in text area of authentication when register the app on developer.uber.com?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, uber-api

When registering an app at https://developer.uber.com/ you can specify a few different URIs

- Redirect URL
- Origin URI
- Privacy Policy URL

What URIs should be set for these fields?

When I enter "localhost" in the redirect url text area and save I get a "Invalid Redirect URL." error.

Answer (score 2):

These are the requirements and notes for each

- Redirect URL

  - Can be in any URL in the form `scheme://host` [read more on URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)
  - This is the [OAuth 2.0](https://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified) redirect URL that your user will be brought to after they authorize your app.
- Origin URI

  - Can be in any URL in the form `scheme://host` [read more on URLs]
  - This is only to be utilized if you plan to issue [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) requests from a browser using bearer tokens
- Privacy Policy URL

  - Must be any http or https URL
  - This is a publicly accessible link to your application's privacy policy.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir..                                                                Sir,                                                                                                             please tell me that how can i build this redirect_url

Comment: Please refer to the OAuth 2.0 link I provided. The redirect URL can be any http/https or mobile app scheme URL. Such as `http://localhost`